# How to mod-rewrite subdomain directory using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have something like this.

http://www.mydomain.com/page.php?s=database&name=page

How do i mod rewrite it in such a way that it become.

**http://www.database.mydomain.com/page/**

I successfully map it into a subdomain format as below using (database.mydomain.com)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+)\.localhost
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ s/index.php?s=%1
```

Have no idea how to proceed further. This is what i have :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+)\.localhost\([^.]+)\
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ s/page.php?name=%1&s=%2
```

Appreciate any expert help. :)

Comment: I see no point in such a rewrite.

Comment: Hi, please kindly explain why there is no point, it will help greatly. thanks

Comment: If it's just a module, why not to call it as a module, `http://www.mydomain.com/database/page/` like everyone else do? Fake subdomains used for the other purpose, such as language select or personal page.

Comment: Oops, i didnt phase my question to sound correctly. U can treat it as http://www.user.mydomain.com/page/ (ignore database). Basically each user will have their own personal profile + pages.

Comment: Well, my answer is correct then. You don't need rewrite for subdomains. Just try it and see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to rewrite subdomains
Rewrite only request uri and be fine.